# Rails - Custom validation of uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validates-uniqueness-of

I want to impart uniqueness on a column (type string), however the problem is on some of the strings I'm truncating part of the beginning before inserting them into the database using a function and `before_save`. Thus the rails uniqueness validation doesn't work since the input might be different from what's in the database, even though after the truncation/formatting, they should be the same.

I want to be able to truncate my string first, then validate it's uniqueness, however I'm not sure if it's possible using the rails `validates uniqueness: true`. Will I just have to write a custom `validate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of Rails callback is:

> (-) save
>
> (-) valid
>
> (1) before_validation
>
> (-) validate
>
> (2) after_validation
>
> (3) before_save
>
> (4) before_create
>
> (-) create
>
> (5) after_create
>
> (6) after_save
>
> (7) after_commit

The detail is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). So you just simply do something like:

```
validates :your_data_field, uniqueness: true
before_validation :normalize_data

def normalize_data
  # Normalize your data here
end
```

So it will work exactly as you described, and don't need to write and custom validation. It will be more beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you'll want to create a custom validator and use validates_with. Information about that is here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_with

To follow DRY principles, and also to ensure any changes to your truncation logic are reflected in both your validator and your before_save callback, I suggest creating a method that returns the truncated string, and use that same method within the validator and the callback.